# Jquery doesn't have an effect on my elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

For whatever reason my jQuery isn't working, yet it seems to work when I put it in JSFiddle. That being said, I assumed the library wasn't importing correctly so i double checked it and everything seemed alright. [Here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ah82G/) is the JSFiddle example. I included all of the code, including the links that I have in my index file. It works perfectly in JSFiddle, but when I try it on my host it doesn't work. I've tried a few browsers but that didn't seem to change anything.

```
<head>
    <title>Artanes Development</title>
</head>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/img/favicon.ico">
<!--Links-->
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300|Abril+Fatface|Vollkorn:400italic,400|Open+Sans:800|Gentium+Book+Basic:400,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
```

Here are all the links i have at the top of my page.

Comment: are you loading this file from a local file sytem(using address file://) or from a local web server

Comment: Any error in console??

Comment: if the file is loaded from local file system then relative scheme technique will not work you will have to specify the complete url like `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js`

Comment: @ArunPJohny I uploaded it to my web hosting FTP and checked if it was working by going to my website link. The jquery link came from the Google Hosted Libraries webpage.

Comment: then see the answer below.... you need to specify the complete url

Comment: can you share the address of the page from your browser address bar

Comment: @ArunPJohny So added the http: just in case to see if it would make a difference and it ended up making it work. Not sure why the google page doesn't have the http: on it. So it's working now, thanks for your help.

Comment: @user2466564 because it uses relative schemes if your page is loaded by `http` or `https` schemes then you can use relative schemes in that case the remote resource will be loaded by the same scheme... but in your case since the pages is loaded using `ftp://` scheme the requested resource will not be available using that scheme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have uploaded the Project to Web hosting FTP.
You should be using:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and not:

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the second one.  It's called the scheme-relative URL, which means it'll pull in `https` if that's the referring site.  http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/

Comment: Yeah, i copied it directly from the Google Hosted Libraries webpage.

Comment: @Dennis:will not work if hosted to FTP. See Arun P. Johnys comment above.

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  You can upload your files via FTP but that has nothing to do with the way you view the site.

Comment: @Dennis And if you're viewing the site via an FTP protocol?

Comment: @Dennis: This even happens when project is hosted using ASP.NET. Loader starts looking into project directory when the path is not absolute.

Comment: @Daedalus Then it would fail, assuming Google doesn't have an FTP server running.  But why would you do that?

Comment: @Dennis I wouldn't, but(I may be wrong) it looks like, from the OP's information, that that's what happened.